# mjpeg video streaming through rtsp

Tags: streaming, rtsp, mjpeg

I am streaming MJPEG data through rtsp protocol i can able to recv data at client side but it displaying grey colored video,i cross check with wireshark it sending jpeg data.except height and width are not correct and also suspecting quantization table how i can set it correctly.  (I AM  Reading frame by frame from file and break into packets.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly you are reconstructing JPEG frame from packets?

Comment: are you able to view any video ?